# Lagrange multipliers over two closed and bounded constraints

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier

> Using Lagrange Multipliers, find all extremum points and the extremum values of the function $$f(x,y,z) = x^2-y^2-z^2$$ subject to the constraints:
> $$x^2+y^2=4$$
> $$y=\sqrt{3+z^2}$$

So far I've done:
$$\text{Lagrange multipliers:}\quad \alpha, \beta \in \Bbb R$$
$$g_1\overset{\large\text{set}}{=}x^2+y^2-4$$
$$g_2\overset{\large\text{set}}{=}\sqrt{3+z^2}-y$$

$$\vec \nabla f = \alpha\vec\nabla g_1 + \beta\vec\nabla g_2$$
$$(2x,-2y,-2z) = \alpha(2x,2y,0) + \beta\left(0,-1,\frac{z}{\sqrt{3+z^2}}\right)$$
So we have
$$\cases{2x=2\alpha x & (1) \\ -2y=2\alpha y - \beta & (2) \\ -2z=\large \frac{\beta z}{\sqrt{3+z^2}} & (3)}$$

From $(1)$ we get $\alpha = 1$.

Putting $\alpha =1$ into $(2)$ we get $$-2y=2y-\beta$$
$$\beta = 4y$$

Putting $\beta = 4y$ into $(3)$, we get
$$-2z=\frac{4yz}{\sqrt{3+z^2}}$$
$$-2z\sqrt{3+z^2}=4yz$$
$$4yz+2z\sqrt{3+z^2}=0$$
$$z\left(4y+2\sqrt{3+z^2}\right)=0$$
So
$$z=0 \quad \text{or} \quad 4y+2\sqrt{3+z^2}=0$$

Putting $z=0$ into $y=\sqrt{3+z^2}$, we get $y=\sqrt{3}$. Putting $y=\sqrt{3}$ into $x^2+y^2=4$, we get $x=\pm 1$. So two critical points are $$(1,\sqrt{3},0) \quad \text{and}\quad (-1,\sqrt{3},0)$$

> But I encounter a problem with the next two critical points:
>
> We have $4y=-2\sqrt{3+z^2}$. If I put this into $y=\sqrt{3+z^2}$, I get a false result.

From here I don't know how to proceed. Any help is appreciated, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello @Patrick Jankowski, the expression in $g_2$ on top, should be $\sqrt{3+z^2}-y$.

Comment: Ah yes good pickup! Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that you arrive at contradictory equations. You just found that in the case $4y + 2\sqrt{3+z^2}=0$, there are no solutions.

I would like to point out that in equation (1) you should consider two different cases. Case 1: $\alpha = 1$ and case 2: $x=0$. The latter case $x=0$ will give you two extra solutions. It follows then from $x^2+y^2=4$ that $y^2=4$, so $y= \pm 2$. But $y=-2$ will give no solution: substituting $y=-2$ in $y-\sqrt{3+z^2}=0$ gives a contradiction. So $y=2$. You can then find that $z=1$ or $-1$.

Comment: You're absolutely right!! I overlooked the possibility $x=0$ from $(1)$. Ok so I'll find the solutions for $x=0$ and then when I come to $4y + 2\sqrt{3+z^2}=0$ I'll state 'for which there are no solutions, therefore the only extrema are ....'. Thanks heaps for the help!!